# How to debug this ant jar command in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, war

im trying to debug an open source project but cannot figure out how to set it up.

I am used to maven, this is an ant project. You can run it from the terminal like this:

```
CLASSPATH=third_party/java/xerces/xercesImpl.jar: ant clean runserver
```

Again,  I have no experience with ant or war files, and in the build.xm it seems to run war files, even though on the command line its calling a jar.

Not sure whether to add a run config for ant target, a jar app, or tomcat. When I tried a jar app I got a missing manifest error.

Any help appreciated, thanks. Happy to add anymore info required, not sure what information is needed to give setup instructions.

EDIT: add runserver from build.xml

```
<target name="runserver" depends="playground,photon,trycaja"
description="Starts the development server.">
<dev_appserver war="ant-war" port="8080">
  <options>
    <arg value="--jvm_flag=-Xmx2048m"/>
    <arg value="--jvm_flag=-Dappengine.user.timezone=UTC"/>
  </options>
</dev_appserver>
```

I tried executing the runserver target as I do on the command line, and it works fine, btu im not sure how to debug it.

Comment: Did you read the Ant help pages of IntelliJ? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/ant.html They are pretty comprehensive.

Comment: I have. As I mentioned, I am not experienced with ant. I tried executing the  runserver target as I do on the command line, and it works fine, btu im not sure how to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the following debug parameter to the `dev_appserver` task:

```
<dev_appserver war="ant-war" port="8080">
  <options>
    <arg value="--jvm_flag=-Xmx2048m"/>
    <arg value="--jvm_flag=-Dappengine.user.timezone=UTC"/>
    <arg value="--jvm_flag=-Xdebug"/>
    <arg value="--jvm_flag=-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005"/>
  </options>
</dev_appserver>
```

and the create a `Remote` debug configuration in IntelliJ on port 5005.